# Autocomplete extender not populating

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I am trying to utilize the [Ajax Auto Complete Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx) with a WCF service that is hosted in the web project.  The service is reached and I have verified that results are returned with fiddler, however the text box associated with the auto complete extender is never populated.

The service contract is as follows:

```
[ScriptService]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public interface ICertificateService
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count);
}
```

The implementation is just returning a populated list of string.

The aspx is as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="aceInstructors"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" 
                                  ID="autoCompleteInstructor"
                                  TargetControlID="aceInstructors"
                                  ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
                                  ServicePath="../../CertificateService" 
                                  MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                                  CompletionInterval="1000" 
                                  EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="5">
                        <Animations>
                            <OnShow>  <HideAction Visible="true" /> </OnShow>
                            <OnHide> <HideAction Visible="false" /> </OnHide>       
                        </Animations>
```

The route for the service is configured in Global.asax as follows:

```
private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("CertificateService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(CertificateService)));
    }
```

As stated before I can hot the service and I get a response in JSON format when I watch in fiddler.  The following is the Raw response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cassini/4.0.1.7
Date: Mon, 12 Sep 2011 16:44:16 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 68
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: Close

{"GetCompletionListResult":["Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta","Omega"]}
```

Something possibly worth noting is that if I omit the ResponseFormat from the Service contract, the reult is returned in XML Format and the text box is populated with a very long list ***undefined***

Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was addressed [here](http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2008/07/07/Ajax-AutoComplete-Extender-with-WCF.aspx).  The issue that I needed to resolve seemed to revolve around the way JSON is wrapped and returned.  It appears that the ajax tool kit autocomplete extender is expecting the JSON content to be '*.d wrapped*'.  This was accomplished by following the configuration settings in the provided link.

It should also be noted that there is an Ajax-Enabled WCF project template that adds these web.config settings...knowing that probably would have saved some time.